# Sandboxing the exec function PHP

Tags: php, sandbox

I am working on a project for a python tutorial website and this entails me allowing users to execute python code on my website. To do this i am using the exec function in PHP, the code is below

```
session_start();


$code = str_replace("\\n", PHP_EOL, $_GET['code']);
$code = str_replace("\\t", "    ", $code);
$filepath = "../tmp/" .  $_SESSION['username'] . (string) rand() . ".py";

$file = fopen($filepath, "w") or die("Cant open file");
fwrite($file, $code);
fclose($file);

$output = null;
exec("python " . $filepath, $output);
unlink($filepath);

foreach( $output as $line )
{
    echo $line;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

What this PHP script does is take the code submitted by the user, save it to a file, execute the file and it then deletes that file. but overly this will allow the user to do what ever they want on my server they can access anything through python. I have implemented some checking of the code before it is executed e.g. checking whether certain library's are used but there are to many to check for them all. i was wondering if there was a way i could sandbox the exec function so if i user tried to use the python library SYS to do something it wouldn't give them access to my system?

Cheers.

Comment: Limit your apache user permissions, as commands executed with the exec function are done so using apache user credentials. You could also try to sanitize the filepath to try to remove any ".." and start the path at a specific folder, but this can be dangerous if not done right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to sandbox the exec, but the [python interpreter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython). Another option is to use chroot.